# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid coordinates passed to jsPDF.addImage

Tags: javascript, html-table, coordinates, jspdf

I am trying to attach an image to the cell right after the last in my table. If I have the last Y coordinate given by jsPDF autotable API (doc.lastAutoTable.finalY), then what should I provide as the X coordinate?

[Where I want it shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtVgY.png)

```
 didDrawPage: data => {
    doc.addImage(
      contactInformation.signatureCanvas,
      'JPEG',
      doc.lastAutoTable.finalY,
      doc.lastAutoTable.finalY
    )
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Should it be finalX instead of finalY on one of them?

```
 didDrawPage: data => {
    doc.addImage(
      contactInformation.signatureCanvas,
      doc.lastAutoTable.finalX,
      doc.lastAutoTable.finalY
    )
  },
```

Comment: Nope. Issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue. I needed to put the

`doc.addImage(contactInformation.signatureCanvas, 'JPEG', 75, doc.autoTable.previous.finalY, 60, 60) outside of the autotable.`